# Full paths of dynamic libraries in crash logs on OS X?

Tags: macos, crash, crash-reports, dynamic-linking, dylib

I have a crash due to the dynamic loading of two different versions of libcairo.

In the crash log I can see the following

```
Binary Images:
...
0x10b80a000 -        0x10b89afef +libcairo.2.dylib (11003.2) <B7DD599A-C397-EDB2-F40B-D1140E51826C> /Users/USER/*/libcairo.2.dylib
0x13082e000 -        0x1308e8ff7 +libcairo.2.dylib (11203.16) <01FBE82F-ACED-3EF4-8448-72B2D29C0970> /Users/USER/*/libcairo.2.dylib
...
```

The paths printed as: `/Users/USER/*/libcairo.2.dylib` and `/Users/USER/*/libcairo.2.dylib`

The interesting parts are replaced by the star.

What I can I do to find the full paths?

FWIW I use OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Any reason you can't just search for those filenames to find out?

Comment: Well I have used mdfind to find likely candidates and used otool -L to see the version numbers. For some reason I can only find the one corresponding to cairo 10.0.2 (11.0.3 in the crash report).

Getting a full path would be easier than searching in the blind.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out to get the full path from the crash log, but here is an alternative:

Open the application with gdb.
Run and provoke the crash.
Write:  `info sharedlibrary`